# How to get count of pull requests made by a user on any repo belonging to an organization?

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to develop a rating system which can list the individuals who have contributed most to my organization on GitHub. I am trying to do that by counting the number of "merged" pull requests created by an user in any of the org's repo.

I am somewhat familiar with GitHub APIs, but I am facing difficulty figuring out the proper requests to make. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you all. Also, it will be nicer if contributions counted this way include those in private repos also.

PS: I don't want to use number of commits as a count, because that is not a precise measure, as in developing a feature some users keep committing one file at time, while others commit after creating a bunch of them. So, please don't suggest that.

Also, there are invalid pull requests also, or some which turn stale, I don't wanna count those in number of contributions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use a [search query](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues-and-pull-requests) to look for issues :

- with type `pr` : `type:pr`
- authored by: `author:{some user}`
- merged: `is:merged`
- in a specific org: `org:{some org}`

The [search query](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Amui-org+author%3Aeps1lon+type%3Apr+is%3Amerged) :

```
org:mui-org author:eps1lon type:pr is:merged
```

The call would be :

https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=org:mui-org%20author:eps1lon%20type:pr%20is:merged

Then filter the total count, an example using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) and [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) :

```bash
curl -s "https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=org:mui-org%20author:eps1lon%20type:pr%20is:merged" | \
     jq '.total_count'
```

Output:

```
715
```

What you could do is using [GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/) to :

- get the list of users in your organization
- build a request dynamically using [aliases](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases) for each user to perform the search query

So you end up with only 2 requests

An example in [python](/questions/tagged/python) :

```python
import requests

token = "YOUR_TOKEN"
org = "mui-org"

userQuery = """
{ 
  organization(login: "%s"){
    membersWithRole(first: 100){
      nodes {
        login
      }
    }
  }
}
"""
pullRequestQuery = """
  %s: search(query: "org:%s author:%s type:pr is:merged", type: ISSUE){
    issueCount
  } 
"""

def makeCall(query):
    r = requests.post("https://api.github.com/graphql",
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"
        },
        json = {
            "query": query
        }
    )
    return r.json()["data"]

userList = makeCall(userQuery % org)

#build a list of keys matching user (user0: johndoe ....)
keyList = {}
for idx, user in enumerate(userList["organization"]["membersWithRole"]["nodes"]):
    keyList[f"user{idx}"] = user["login"]

#build the query
builtQuery = "".join([
    pullRequestQuery % (t, org, keyList[t]) 
    for t in keyList.keys()
])
result = makeCall("{%s}" % builtQuery)

#match the original user login
stats = {}
for it in result.keys():
    stats[keyList[it]] = result[it]["issueCount"]

print(stats)
```

output :

```json
{'kof': 1, 'pelotom': 57, 'mbrookes': 487, 'dtassone': 78, 'sebald': 29, 'hai-cea': 14, 'kgregory': 21, 'oliviertassinari': 2077, 'merceyz': 70, 'nathanmarks': 80, 'mnajdova': 56, 'leMaik': 45, 'DanailH': 4, 'alitaheri': 98, 'm2mathew': 6, 'eps1lon': 715, 'DDDDDanica': 13, 'joshwooding': 110, 'dimitropoulos': 2, 'dmtrKovalenko': 352}
```

Comment: If the search is across the organisation, the search query must be run at the github organisation level

Answer (score 1):

A larger, but potentially more maintainable solution is to collect webhooks into a database.  Once it is there you can build any metrics you might want on your organization's activity, including pull request counts.

I have written an article detailing the process that uses Fivetran, Snowflake, and Visivo to accomplish this.

Here is the article,

https://medium.com/@tim_23622/quickly-create-a-github-dashboard-using-visivo-10371f1dfea1

But the overall process is:

`Github Webook -> Fivetran -> Snowflake (Or other) -> Visualize with Visivo`

Full disclosure, I helped write Visivo for just these use cases, so I think it is pretty great. :-)